# How to set threeview node checkbox to mix state i.e. if any of the child node is selected, Parent node should fill in to indicate that

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I am working on a windows form application, where I connect to the database and get a list of projects and sub-projects. I am able to show this as a treeview with checkboxes, that later an user can select to do further operations.

My problem is that, I can't set the Parent node state when one of the child nodes is selected. Here, I want some indication, if any of the child nodes is selected the parent node should fill in to show that something has been selected below that parent node.

[image: This is something, I want to do]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, meanwhile, I found answer to my problem. Not really wise but thanks to this Simple Tri-State TreeView control.  [code link here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59514/Simple-Tri-State-TreeView)

I will definitely try to build my own custom version of this. For now, this works fine.